# Google Maps API v3 - maxZoomService

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to understand the [maxZoomService](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maxzoom).

What I can read from the documentation:

> Most **roadmap imagery** is available from zoom levels 0 to 18, for example.

Then

> The `MaxZoomService` object provides a simple interface for discovering the maximum zoom level at a given location for which Google Maps has **satellite imagery**.

Now how would I know the maximum zoom level available for other imagery such as roadmap or terrain? I get zoom on roadmap up to level 21 in many places. If I'd use an external zoom slider, how can I know what is available?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

He're the source code of the MaxZoomService, it seems like there is no option or any other functions allowing you to do that :/

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.lynden/GMapsFX/1.1.1/com/lynden/gmapsfx/zoom/MaxZoomService.java#MaxZoomService.%3Cinit%3E%28%29

```
public class More ...MaxZoomService extends JavascriptObject {

    private MaxZoomServiceCallback callback;

    public MaxZoomService() {
        super(GMapObjectType.MAX_ZOOM_SERVICE);
    }

    public void getMaxZoomAtLatLng(LatLong loc, MaxZoomServiceCallback callback) {

        this.callback = callback;

        JSObject doc = (JSObject) getJSObject().eval("document");
        doc.setMember(getVariableName(), this);

        StringBuilder r = new StringBuilder(getVariableName())
              .append(".")
              .append("getMaxZoomAtLatLng(")
              .append(loc.getVariableName())
              .append(", ")
              .append("function(result) {document.")
              .append(getVariableName())
              .append(".processResponse(result);});");

        System.out.println("MaxZoomService direct call: " + r.toString());

        getJSObject().eval(r.toString());

    }
}
```

I guess you'll have to hardcode it to 18. Another option would be to check for 19, 20, 21, but that'd be far too slow, as you have to wait a response from Google.